# The commerce_product.field_produit_labels field needs to be updated

Tags: 8, entities, commerce, drush, updating

almost every time I delete a field in my product types I get this message popping up in my dashboard :

> ENTITY/FIELD DEFINITIONS Mismatched entity and/or field definitions
> The following changes were detected in the entity type and field
> definitions. Product The commerce_product.field_produit_labels field
> needs to be updated.

It has not been possible to update entities with "Drush" for some time.

Why do I have these problems regularly ? This is only with the Commerce module.

How can I correct this? Without breaking my site.

```
ubuntu@ov-b2b650 ~/www-example-com $ drush entup

In UpdateDBCommands.php line 110:
                                                                                                    
  Drupal removed its automatic entity-updates API in 8.7. See https://www.drupal.org/node/3034742.  
                                                                                                    

entity:updates [--cache-clear [CACHE-CLEAR]] [--no-cache-clear] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-d|--debug] [-y|--yes] [--no] [--remote-host REMOTE-HOST] [--remote-user REMOTE-USER] [-r|--root ROOT] [-l|--uri URI] [--simulate] [--pipe] [-D|--define DEFINE] [--druplicon] [--xh-link XH-LINK] [--notify] [--] <command>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can quick-fix it by adding module devel_entity_updates https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_entity_updates and run the command drush entup.
Don't forget to export configurations after that.

Also, you can fix it by manually creating an update hook - follow https://www.drupal.org/node/3034742#comment-13097250

Comment: Ok thank you, why do you have to export ?

Comment: just to be safe if something changed and that configuration is same as in database

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable or install the devel entity updates first before running `drush entup` command.

**Install Devel Entity Updates Module with composer** (Source: https://www.drupal.org/project/devel_entity_updates)

`composer require 'drupal/devel_entity_updates:^3.0'`
(or `composer require drupal/devel_entity_updates`to automatically get the latest version)

**Enable Devel Entity Updates Module**

`drush en devel_entity_updates`

Hope this will work for you.